# How should I set _auth in .npmrc when using a Nexus https npm registry proxy?

Tags: npm, nexus, npm-install

**Context**

1. My `.npmrc` file seems to be correctly read (checked with `npm config ls -l` both from command line and from Maven build).
2. the machine on which `npm` is run cannot connect directly to the net, it can only connect to a Nexus npm registry url. Therefore, proxy properties `proxy` and `https-proxy` are not set.
3. As access to Nexus is restricted, I have generated an access token from within Nexus.
4. Nexus security tokens are made from a username and a password which both contain characters such as `/` which usually have to be "url encoded"
5. as expected, with this configuration, when running `npm install` detects no proxy.
6. Nexus npm registry proxy seems to be correctly set (I can both access `json` files and download `tgz` files using a web browser after having connected using the token generated)
7. If I set `registry` to `http://registry.npmjs.org/` and comment `_auth`, `email`, `always-auth`, `strict-ssl` properties, and add `proxy` and `https-proxy` configuration, `npm install` works as expected (but I won't be able to do it on target environment)

**Content of `.npmrc` file**

```
; Nexus proxy registry pointing to http://registry.npmjs.org/
registry = https://<host>/nexus/content/repositories/npmjs-registry/ 

; base64 encoded authentication token
_auth = <see question below>

; required by Nexus
email = <valid email>

; force auth to be used for GET requests
always-auth = true

; we don't want to put certificates in .npmrc
strict-ssl = false

loglevel = silly
```

**Question**

How should I generate the `_auth` property properly in order to have `npm install` work as expected?

**I tried so far**

1. base64Encode(`<username>:<password>`)

   - results in `npm info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: socket hang up`
2. base64Encode(urlencode(`<username>:<password>`))

   - results in `` npm info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: This request requires auth credentials. Run `npm login` and repeat the request. ``
3. base64Encode(urlencode(`<username>`)`:`urlencode(`<password>`))

   - results in `npm info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: socket hang up`

When getting the `socket hang up` error I have the following stack trace:

```
http request GET https://<host>/nexus/content/repositories/npmjs-registry/fsevents
sill fetchPackageMetaData Error: socket hang up
sill fetchPackageMetaData     at TLSSocket.onHangUp (_tls_wrap.js:1035:19)
sill fetchPackageMetaData     at TLSSocket.g (events.js:260:16)
sill fetchPackageMetaData     at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
sill fetchPackageMetaData     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:166:7)
sill fetchPackageMetaData     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:905:12)
sill fetchPackageMetaData     at doNTCallback2 (node.js:441:9)
sill fetchPackageMetaData     at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:17)
sill fetchPackageMetaData  error for fsevents@^1.0.0 { [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET' }
WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: socket hang up
verb install Error: socket hang up
verb install     at TLSSocket.onHangUp (_tls_wrap.js:1035:19)
verb install     at TLSSocket.g (events.js:260:16)
verb install     at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
verb install     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:166:7)
verb install     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:905:12)
verb install     at doNTCallback2 (node.js:441:9)
verb install     at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:17)
```

When getting the `This request requires auth credentials` error I have the following stack trace:

```
npm sill fetchPackageMetaData Error: This request requires auth credentials. Run `npm login` and repeat the request.
npm sill fetchPackageMetaData     at CachingRegistryClient.authify (<root>\ui\target\node\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\authify.js:17:14)
npm sill fetchPackageMetaData     at CachingRegistryClient.makeRequest (<root>\ui\target\node\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:103:17)
npm sill fetchPackageMetaData     at <root>\ui\target\node\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:66:17
npm sill fetchPackageMetaData     at RetryOperation._fn (<root>\ui\target\node\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\attempt.js:18:5)
npm sill fetchPackageMetaData     at null._onTimeout (<root>\ui\target\node\node_modules\npm\node_modules\retry\lib\retry_operation.js:49:10)
npm sill fetchPackageMetaData     at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)
npm sill fetchPackageMetaData  error for fsevents@^1.0.0 [Error: This request requires auth credentials. Run `npm login` and repeat the request.]
npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: This request requires auth credentials. Run `npm login` and repeat the request.
npm verb install Error: This request requires auth credentials. Run `npm login` and repeat the request.
npm verb install     at CachingRegistryClient.authify (<root>\ui\target\node\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\authify.js:17:14)
npm verb install     at CachingRegistryClient.makeRequest (<root>\ui\target\node\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:103:17)
npm verb install     at <root>\ui\target\node\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:66:17
npm verb install     at RetryOperation._fn (<root>\ui\target\node\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\attempt.js:18:5)
npm verb install     at null._onTimeout (<root>\ui\target\node\node_modules\npm\node_modules\retry\lib\retry_operation.js:49:10)
npm verb install     at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)
```

Comment: try to execute command `npm login` - it will ask you for credentials and updane .npmrc with _authToken section

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After having looked at `registry-client` code I found the answer, here it is. I post it as it may help other people:

```
base64Encode(<username>:<password>)
```

By the way, there is an URL encoding, but it's `authify.js` that takes care of it.

The "socket hang up" problem I'm facing is due to the fact that if a proxy is set in Windows configuration, when launching `npm` from CLI (and not from a Maven build) all ```.npmrc`` proxy settings seem to be ignored while native proxy exclusions (for corporate urls) are ignored by npm. I'll open a ticket to report this weird behavior.

Comment: How different is this answer from what you wrote in question ( " base64Encode(<username>:<password>)
results in npm info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: socket hang up ") ?

Answer (score 74):

Sources: https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/nexus-repository-administration/formats/npm-registry/npm-security
& https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/nexus-repository-administration/formats/npm-registry/publishing-npm-packages

1. Configure registry (its important doing this before configuring the authentication in step 2, because the authentication settings will be based on the registry):

   ```
    npm config set registry="http://localhost:8081/repository/npm-internal/"
   ```
2. Configure authentication using a line like the following example:

   ```
    npm config set _auth="$(echo -n 'username:password' | base64)"
   ```
3. Check the current configuration using the following:

   ```
    npm config ls
   ```
4. Publish your npm package:

   ```
    npm publish --registry http://localhost:8081/repository/npm-internal/
   ```

Comment: Seems that you can use just "base64" (without "openssl"). It also seems that "-n" flag is critical, since adding it to my script made it work at last

Comment: dont forget about -n . Otherwsie you will get into trouble!

Comment: the link has changed. now it is https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/formats/npm-registry#npmRegistry-AuthenticationUsingBasicAuth

Comment: Adding `-n` to `echo` is very important

Comment: Not work! the last step yields this error `npm ERR! code ERR_INVALID_AUTH`.  npm version 10.1.0

Comment: The base64 authentication doesn't work in the newer versions of npm.

Answer (score 26):

If you have authorization token you should not use username:password.
I suggest you:

1. Generate token

- Delete your `~/.npmrc` or rename it.
- Make sure your env settings like `$NPM_CONFIG_*` are unset.
- Verify that email and other settings are unset by using: `npm config list`
- Log into the npm using: `npm login --registry=https://nexus.whatever.registry/respository/npm-whatever-group/`
- Once you are logged - you are logged. The npm should generate a token for it in your `~/.npmrc`. It will look like:

`//nexus.whatever.registry/respository/npm-whatever-group/:_authToken=NpmToken.YOUR-LOVELY-TOKEN-IN-HEX`

2. You can use that token in your project, CI pipeline, and other ones. Make sure in your project `.npmrc` there is:

`//nexus.whatever.registry/respository/npm-whatever-group/:_authToken=NpmToken.YOUR-LOVELY-TOKEN-IN-HEX email = <EMAIL_USED_FOR_TOKEN_GENERATION> always-auth = true registry = https://nexus.whatever.registry/respository/npm-whatever-group/`

3. If you have problems with authentication/certs:

- add env variable (also to your CI/CD pipeline)
  $NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS to point to /home/wherever/is/your/cert.pem

4. For CI/CD pipelines (like GitLab or Jenkins):

- consider replacing actual values from your `.npmrc` project file with `${RELEVANT_ENV_VARIABLES}`. This way you will make them less visible and always self-updating on change of pipeline.

Hope this help.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer but pops up as a last answer

Answer (score 8):

```
Before you run npm login, please follow the instructions below :

1) Create an ~/.npmrc file with the following contents:

registry=https://example.com/repository/npm-group/
email=username@example.com
always-auth=true
//example.com/repository/npm-group/:_authToken=

2) run `npm login`

# npm login
Username: firstname.lastname
Password: 
Email: (this IS public) firstname.lastname@example.com
Logged in as firstname,lastname on https://example.com/repository/npm-group/.

Use the same password you use to login to example.com
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about Nexus, but we use artifactory as an npm repo, and there I can create my auth token by calling `base64encode(username:encryptedPassword)` with `encryptedPassword` being the one I get from my personal artifactory profile.

Maybe this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I have my npmrc like:

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
@mycompany:registry=https://nexus.mycompany.ninja/repository/npm-hosted/
//nexus.mycompany.ninja/repository/npm-hosted/:_auth="this is my real auth secret="
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a wrapper that stores the credentials in your systems keychain and provides them on the fly. Check out: https://github.com/Xiphe/npm_keychain_auth

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my "_auth" variable was not updated, I did these things -

1. npm config set _auth
2. npm config fix
3. yarn install/npm install

token = Base64 of username:password