# Can not "npm publish" to internally-hosted npm repository?

Tags: npm, nexus3, npm-publish

I followed [Using Nexus 3 as Your Repository – Part 2: npm Packages](https://blog.sonatype.com/using-nexus-3-as-your-repository-part-2-npm-packages) to set up an internal npm repository.

I'm then able to do this,

```
$ npm view jsreport dist.tarball
https://registry.npmjs.org/jsreport/-/jsreport-3.0.1.tgz
```

I have this in my `~/.npmrc` file

```
$ cat ~/.npmrc
//internal_nexus_url:8081/repository/:_authToken=NpmToken.43b77b61-2492-39b8-8150-38555f6b6943
```

I have this in my `/path_to_project/.npmrc` file

```
registry="http://internal_nexus_url:8081/repository/npm-private/_auth=base64_user_pw"
```

and this in my `/path_to_project/package.json` file

```
{
  ...
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "http://internal_nexus_url:8081/repository/npm-private"
  },
  ...
}
```

When do an `npm publish` I get

```
npm notice === Tarball Details === 
npm notice name:          my-package                            
npm notice version:       2.4.4                                   
npm notice filename:      my-package-2.4.4.tgz                  
npm notice package size:  141.6 MB                                
npm notice unpacked size: 421.1 MB                                
npm notice shasum:        09c134ef93ce70e999d62820b5bffc6cf23765f3
npm notice integrity:     sha512-X5iqe9DV03MPG[...]TKvNZO4O8ToyQ==
npm notice total files:   17559                                   
npm notice 
npm ERR! code ENEEDAUTH
npm ERR! need auth This command requires you to be logged in.
npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /patch/.npm/_logs/2021-11-16T21_48_03_450Z-debug.log
```

The error file above basically says the same thing. So I follow the instructions, and do

```
$ npm adduser
$ npm adduser
npm notice Log in on http://internal_nexus_url:8081/repository/exa-npm-private/_auth=base64_user_pw
Username: nexus-user
Password: 
Email: (this IS public) nexus@kmha.com
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: BASIC realm="Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /path/.npm/_logs/2021-11-16T21_52_29_060Z-debug.log
```

What's preventing me from publishing to my internal npm repo?

UPDATE:

I modified my `~/.npmrc` file to include the information on [How should I set _auth in .npmrc when using a Nexus https npm registry proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35043155/how-should-i-set-auth-in-npmrc-when-using-a-nexus-https-npm-registry-proxy) to no avail.

Comment: did you do `npm login --registry=http://internal_nexus_url:8081/repository/npm-private`

Comment: Thanks, and yes I did that.

Comment: Is the "npm Bearer Token Realm" is made active in "http://internal_nexus_url:8081#admin/security/realms"?

Comment: Have you managed to fix this? I have the same issue on npm v9 when trying to `npm publish`.